# What does it mean in ruby when there are more than one values after = separed by , assigned to a single variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Specifically how does this work

```
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store, "cache.example.com", { pool_size: 5, pool_timeout: 5 }
```

Sometimes just two values are assigned like

```
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store, "cache.example.com"
```

Comment: That’s [Implicit Array Assignment](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Implicit+Array+Assignment). `a = x, y, z` is equivalent to `a = [x, y, z]` – you can just omit the brackets.